# R passing SQL results to sql statement

Tags: mysql, sql, r, rmysql

I am pulling some results from MySQL database like below:

```
GetJobCodes=paste0("select EMPLID from jobCurrent where JOBCODE='",JOBCODE,"'")
JOBCODES = dbGetQuery(connection,GetJobCodes)
```

and I want to pass above JOBCODES results to other SQL statement

```
statement=sprintf("SELECT A.EMPLID, A.CLASS_ID FROM lmsEnroll A JOIN lmsCourses\ 
              B ON A.COURSE_ID=B.COURSE_ID AND B.REQUIRED=0 WHERE A.EMPLID IN (%s)",JOBCODES)
```

But when I am passing to above statement it is print like

```sql
SELECT A.EMPLID, A.CLASS_ID FROM lmsEnroll A JOIN lmsCourses\ 
       B ON A.COURSE_ID=B.COURSE_ID AND B.REQUIRED=0 WHERE A.EMPLID IN "C("00330022","00033322")")
```

which is not correct, I want to print them like :

```sql
SELECT A.EMPLID, A.CLASS_ID FROM lmsEnroll A JOIN lmsCourses\ 
       B ON A.COURSE_ID=B.COURSE_ID AND B.REQUIRED=0 WHERE A.EMPLID IN ("00330022","00033322")
```

I have used ShQuote function, but it is not help. I appreciate if anyone could help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it! This issue all about rendering thing. By selecting EMPLID with JOBCODES dataframe got issue resolved .

```
JOBCODES =paste(shQuote(JOBCODES$EMPLID,type="sh"),collapse=",") //Selecting EMPLID column

statement=paste0("SELECT A.EMPLID, A.CLASS_ID FROM lmsEnroll A JOIN lmsCourses B ON A.COURSE_ID=B.COURSE_ID AND B.REQUIRED=0 WHERE A.EMPLID IN 
(",JOBCODES,")")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `glue` to do this.

```
library(glue)

GetJobCodes <- paste0("select EMPLID from jobCurrent where JOBCODE='",JOBCODE,"'")
JOBCODES <- dbGetQuery(connection,GetJobCodes)
statement <- "SELECT A.EMPLID, A.CLASS_ID FROM lmsEnroll A JOIN lmsCourses\ 
              B ON A.COURSE_ID=B.COURSE_ID AND B.REQUIRED=0 WHERE A.EMPLID IN ({JOBCODES})"
request <- glue_sql(statement,JOBCODES = JOBCODES, .con = connection)
```

Comment: i forgot to remove "sprintf", that change something ?

Answer (score 0):

Consider one query with parameterization (avoiding quote handling or concatenation) as you can use a `SELECT` statement inside an `IN` clause:

```
sql <- "SELECT A.EMPLID, A.CLASS_ID 
        FROM lmsEnroll A 
        JOIN lmsCourses B ON A.COURSE_ID=B.COURSE_ID AND B.REQUIRED=0 
        WHERE A.EMPLID IN
           (SELECT EMPLID FROM jobCurrent WHERE JOBCODE = ?)"

emp_df <- dbGetQuery(connection, sql, list(JOBCODE))
```

Alternatively, with a `JOIN`:

```
sql <- "SELECT A.EMPLID, A.CLASS_ID 
        FROM lmsEnroll A 
        INNER JOIN lmsCourses B 
              ON A.COURSE_ID = B.COURSE_ID AND B.REQUIRED = 0 
        INNER JOIN 
             (SELECT DISTINCT EMPLID FROM jobCurrent WHERE JOBCODE = ?) sub
              ON A.EMPLID IN sub.EMPLID"

emp_df <- dbGetQuery(connection, sql, list(JOBCODE))
```

Comment: this query is taking too long to get the results, so I am trying this way.

Comment: Does your database have an index on `EMPLID` in *lmsEnroll* and *jobCurrent* tables?

Comment: How slow is it? How much data is involved? Does same *poor performance* occur in MySQL?

Comment: it is slow in MySQL as well

Comment: Again, are we talking about millions of rows? And is your interpretation of slow: 5 secs, 5 mins, 50 mins?

Comment: I add a `JOIN` version. If rows are not into millions and performance runs over 5 mins., it must be [indexing](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/14581). Try a compound index of `EMPLID` and `JOBCODE` in *jobCurrent* table.